# lm358 arranged as a 5 volt Buffer

Tags: voltage, amplifier, buffer

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8ntoDm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to connect my lm358 so that it acts like a buffer.  I am connecting:

- VCC to + 5 volts
- Ground to Ground
- Non-inverting input to +5 volts
- Inverting input to output.

According to my research, connecting the output to the inverting input should cause the output to have the same voltage as the input (+5 volts.)  However, I an getting 3.7 volts.  Am I making a mistake here, or is the chip damaged or mislabeled?  Should I be adding a resister or capacitor into this configuration somewhere?

Edit:  I tested this design with +9 volts to the VCC and it was able to produce +5 volts on the output.  Then, when I applied +9 volts to the non-inverting input, the IC produced 8.17 volts on the output.

Comment: We love schematics. Please add one using the button on the editor toolbar. Add links to datasheets.

Comment: @transistor The problem with simple schematics and CircuitLab is that the image then becomes huge and it really obfuscates the question. Hopefully, a [workaround](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5595/circuitlab-schematic-integration-we-still-get-huge-diagrams-after-3-years-any#comment12840_5595) has been found.

Comment: I know. I always add a little 't' (for transistor) at the bottom right of mine to scale them properly. It also helps me recognise my own work when I come back to it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LM358 is not a rail-to-rail output opamp. So it means it is not able to drive its outputs hard enough to reach the supply voltage. There will always be a voltage drop even when it saturates. This exists both on the high side and, to a lesser extent, low side.

See the datasheet to know the magnitude of this drop (which depends on the current you need on the output - the more you draw, the bigger the drop):

**For the high side**:

[image: Output characteristic current sourcing]

**For the low side**:

[image: Output characteristic current sinking]

Comment: Putput Op-Amp? I like it! (Though note needs to be made of the 358's nearly rail-reaching output when it comes to the low supply. To fractions of a volt.)

Comment: @Asmyldof Argh, damn iPad... Anway, the answer wasn't detailed enough as I wasn't posting from my PC. I edited it.

Answer (score 4):

An LM358's output cannot go up to the +ve rail, only within a couple of volts. If you ask it to buffer a 3v voltage you should be OK. If you want to buffer 5v, you need at least a 7v power supply.

... as you found with your 9v supply experiment.